# How do I interpret the !found in the given Java code

Tags: java

```
boolean contains(Node head, Object target) {
    boolean found;
    Node currentNode = head;

    while (currentNode != null && **!found **){
        if (target.equals(currentNode.data))
            found = true;
        else
            currentNode = currentNode.next;
    }
    return found;
}
```

The above code is given in the textbook for linear search.

I think the !found is for decreasing the time of searching. As long as the target was found, we get rid of the loop at once.

However, what does !found exactly mean? We did not define the value of found as true or false before approaching the loop....

Comment: found is a `boolean`. `!` is the sign for "not", which makes `true` -> `false` and `false` -> `true`. In other words, it means "not found". So your loop says "While we have a node to check and didn't find the right one yet..."

Comment: That's right. However, the point about why `found` is not defined as `true` or `false` is also valid. Running this would result in a `The local variable found may not have been initialized` error. `found` should be initialized to `false` for here I think

Comment: This won't compile. It should be probably be `boolean found = false;`.

Comment: I guess we are on the same page. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @shmosel this compiles pretty well. You do not need the initialization, as `boolean` primitives are initialized to false by default.

Comment: @P.J.Meisch There is no default initialization for local variables.